# PHP/SQL search dependent on two fields

Tags: php, sql, search

I'm working on a place where you can search a user by their full name. The problem i've run into is right now it's two separate fields for first and last name. I'm trying to do a search where if someone types "Jon Smith" it looks for the people with the name "Jon Smith". I know I could explode the variable given and search with the exploded variable, but that has some flaws too. But I wanted to know if there is any other way to fix this other than exploding a variable or setting up another field.

Comment: what are the flaws of `explode()`?

Comment: Actually, the flaw I was thinking of would have been a programmers mistake. So never mind. I was sitting here re-reading my post and thought "Wait, if you do this it wouldn't matter"

Comment: How is this not a real question? "But I wanted to know if there is any other way to fix this other than exploding a variable or setting up another field." I think that sentence alone is a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a full-text index to use a full text search directly in your database. This way it would be irrelevant if someone types those values in another order. Also this can give you a score value if someone types in a username which does not exactly match your query if that is what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You **should** explode it. What if he searches for Smith John when it's in your database as John Smith?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the use in making it more difficult with not exploding it.